# Excel's Worksheet Change event not firing unless cell is manually changed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am using the following code which works great.  However, changes to the cell that should fire this event are made using a formula not an entry in the cell.  If I type in the entry, everything works.  But if I use a formula to grab the data from another worksheet, it does not. For instance, the cells in AD have formulas like `=HR!P27`.

What am I missing?

Code:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Update 20140722
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("AD:AD"), Target)
    xOffsetColumn = -1
    If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each Rng In WorkRng
           If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
              Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
              Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
           Else
             Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
           End If
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

A formula that returns a different result does not qualify as a change to a cell. According to the description of the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event, it:

> Occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link.

This behavior makes sense when you observe that the cell's content isn't actually changing.  For example, the cell contained `=HR!P27` before **and** after the formula returned a different result. Only the formula's result changed. As this case affirms, Excel distinguishes between changes that affect a cell's content vs. its output.

If you need your code to run each time your formula updates, consider using the [Worksheet_Calculate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-calculate-event-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event. It fires each time the worksheet is recalculated.

Comment: I tried to do that but now get an error. Can anyone help me write this correctly using Worksheet_Calculate?

Comment: You need to ask a [new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). You can link to this question to provide context if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Consider the Range("AD:AD") in your VBA code, I would like to suggest you the reason behind and also solutions that how could you fix the issue**

If the Range is **Manually Refreshed** (what you have done in fact), then the **Change Event can be used.**

If the Range **contains any Formula**, then the **Calculate Event can be used.**

If the Range **contains a value that is refreshed via an external data or Formula**, then in Range("AD"AD") enters =("AD:AD") and the **Calculate Event can then also be used.**

Thaes are the possible reasons. So if the Range gets refreshed, then AD:AD will automatically be calculated and the event will be triggered.

I guess that you have not entered the code under **ThisWorkbook.** The code is required to enter under **Sheet**, then it works.

*So that the conclusion is use Calculate Event.*

**Below are two sample coding methods, help you to get rid from the situation.**

**Method 1:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("AD:AD")

    If Not Intersect(target, Range("AD:AD")) Is Nothing Then

    PASTE YOUR VB CODE HERE.

    End If

End Sub
```

**Method 2:**

Simply create this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Worksheet_Change Range("AD:AD")
End Sub
```

**NB:** *This code will take care of your existing "Worksheet Change Event" exercise.*

*I do hope this help you.*

Comment: When I try this I get an error

Comment: When I paste my code where you suggested, I get an "Expected End Sub" error that points to the line 4.  "If Not Intersect (Target, Range("AD:AD")) Is Nothing then  .....thereafter all my code is pasted.

Comment: Putting code in the Calculate event that triggers code in the Change event will result in the Change event being fired in duplicate under certain circumstances. This is unlikely to be desirable behavior.

Comment: @Terrib while Paste your code just remove Line Private Sub Worksheet_Change and End Sub,, in fact you have Pasted the Entire Code including Private Sub,,, and End Sub. It will work.